# How can I prevent clipped portions of subviews from still taking touch events?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit

I'm currently clipping some UIViews within a parent view like in the illustration below:

[image: illustration of subviews clipped to a superview]

The problem is that the clipped portions (the invisible portions) of the subviews are still receiving touch events that, intuitively, should be going to the other views visible there.

Is there something else I should be doing to achieve this behavior, or is this not actually an easy thing to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was happening because the parent view in this case had a custom implementation of

`- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`,

and it wasn't performing this bounds test (which I now assume is part of the default implementation).

Adding:

```
if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
    ....
}
```

around the code in that implementation solved the problem.

Comment: It won't let me accept my own answer for 2 days, but don't worry, I intend to!

Comment: Oh, I had no idea that restriction existed.  Cool.  I gave you +1 btw, on both Question and Answer b/c I ran into a very similar problem yesterday, so I appreciate your post and answer.